# Android Dialog EditText doesn't give value

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

I'm trying to get the text from a Dialog, but it doesn't work. All the code works except `username = txtDialog.getText().toString();`

I get a NullpointerException

Here is the complete code :

```
btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog  = new Dialog(ResActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialog.show();

            Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
            declineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    txtDialog = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
                    username = txtDialog.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EndActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_NAME, username);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: edittext is in dialog??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `Edittext` inside `Dialog`
Change this line

```
txtDialog = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
```

into

```
txtDialog = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
txtDialog = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
```

Comment: @Yves please accept answer if is it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

your edit text inside in dialog i.e use like this

```
txtDialog = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `EditText` inside of your dialog:

then change this declaration line

From

```
txtDialog = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
```

To

```
txtDialog = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

void connectToHotSpot() {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

```
        alert.setTitle("Inpaint Server");

        alert.setMessage("IP Address");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);


        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            String nickname=input.getText().toString();
            if(!nickname.equals(""))
            {
                Variables.Serversip=nickname;
                ipaddress.setText("Server's IP "+nickname);
                showAlertMessage("Message","Ok.Proceed");
            }
            else
            {
                showAlertMessage("Oops","Specify the Server's IP Address");
            }

         }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Must give me the IP B4 Inpainting",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
        }
        });

         alert.show();
    }
```